# Procedure Limit

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I need help please! I tried searching for answers but didn't find anything.

I am using MYSQL6.

### What I did is create 2 views and I want to limit these views to get a specific amount of results that is calculated through a function.

FUNCTION:

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE FUNCTION `get_total_customers`() RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN

DECLARE TotalCustomers INT;

SELECT (count(customer_id)*0.2) INTO TotalCustomers FROM customer;

RETURN TotalCustomers;
END
```

---

VIEW1:

```
    CREATE VIEW PreferredStatus AS 
SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount, get_total_customers() AS Total FROM payment
GROUP BY customer_id 
ORDER BY TotalAmount DESC;
```

---

VIEW2:

```
    CREATE VIEW RegularStatus AS
SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount, get_total_customers() AS Total FROM payment
GROUP BY customer_id 
ORDER BY TotalAmount ASC
LIMIT Total;
```

This is the procedure that would use the view.

```
 > DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `CustomerStatus`(in custID int, out status varchar(200))
BEGIN

declare number1 int;
declare totalvar int;
declare limit2 int;

IF custID in (SELECT customer_id FROM PreferredStatus) THEN 
    set status = "preferred";

ELSEIF custID in (SELECT customer_id FROM RegularStatus) THEN  
    set status = "casual";

ELSE
    set status = "regular";

End If; 
END
```

---

HELP PLEASE!

-Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem?  Errors?  Unexpected results?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `LIMIT` to the `SELECT` that creates the `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW PreferredStatus AS 
SELECT customer_id, 
       SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount, 
       get_total_customers() AS Total 
FROM payment
GROUP BY customer_id 
ORDER BY TotalAmount DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06492/1)</kbd>

A warning from [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html):

> If a view definition includes a LIMIT clause, and you select from the
>   view using a statement that has its own LIMIT clause, it is undefined
>   which limit applies.